# Laravel Crud Editing makes a new record

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with my Laravel crud application for Registrations.
There are these tables: **Registration**, **ExtraRegistration** (with a registration_id, extra_id and extraoptions_id),
**Extra**  and **ExtraOptions** (with the Extra_id).

In the RegistrationController when i add a Registration it makes a new record in the ExtraRegistration with the extraoptions_id and the extra_id. the extra_id is the name of the option and the extraoptions_id is the id of the option you selected.

But now, when you click on edit a record, it shows all the information. the problem is that when you change the extraoption, it makes another record, and not change the select.
And when you have edited something and you look at it again, it still shows the option before you edited it.

**RegistrationController**

```
$options = Extra::where("exa_form_id", $distance->asd_form_id)->get();
    foreach($options as $option){
      $input_name = "option_" . $option->exa_id;
      $input_option = $request->$input_name;
      if(!is_null($input_option)){
         $input_name_extra = "extraoptions_" . $option->exa_id;
         $input_option_extra = $request->$input_name_extra;                      

         $registrationextra = new ExtraRegistration();
         $registrationextra->iea_registration_id = $registration->isg_id;
         $registrationextra->iea_extra_id = $input_option;
         $registrationextra->iea_extraoption_id = $input_option_extra;
         $registrationextra->iea_price = $option->exa_price;
         $registrationextra->save();

         }               

       }

$registration->isg_options = $input_option;
$registration->isg_option_extra_id = $input_option_extra;
```

I want a check before it makes a new ExtraRegistration. that it only makes a new registration if the registration_id with that extra_id doesn't already exists. (Not 100% sure though).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Duplicate [Laravel Crud Application Editing a record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58915322/laravel-crud-application-editing-a-record) - please don't post the same question multiple times

Answer (score 0):

you make a new object of ExtraRegistration so its always make a new entry for update first get object of those id after that update
check the below link

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#updates

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you're creating a new `ExtraRegistration` record:

```
$registrationextra = new ExtraRegistration();
```

If you want to update it, you need to find the related `$registrationextra` for your `$options`, and then update them (assuming you have relations set up):

```
$registrationextra = ExtraRegistration::where('options_id', $option->id);
$registrationextra->update([
   'your_fields' => value
   // etc...
]);
```

If you want to check if ExtraRegistration exists, and depending on that, create or update it, you can do something like this:

```
$registrationextra = App\ExtraRegistration::updateOrCreate(
    ['your_fields' => 'value'],
);
```

You can read more on official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent).

Comment: so i cant use an if else to check? because it has to be a check

Comment: You can, you don't have to do it like this.

Comment: could you give me an example with the if else?