# Laravel Crud Application Editing a record

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with my Laravel crud application for Registrations.
There are these tables: **Registration**, **ExtraRegistration** (with a registration_id, extra_id and extraoptions_id),
**Extra**  and **ExtraOptions** (with the Extra_id).

In the RegistrationController when i add a Registration it makes a new record in the ExtraRegistration with the extraoptions_id and the extra_id. the extra_id is the name of the option and the extraoptions_id is the id of the option you selected.

But now, when you click on edit a record, it shows all the information. the problem is that when you change the extraoption, it makes another record, and not change the select.
And when you have edited something and you look at it again, it still shows the option before you edited it.

**RegistrationController**

```
$options = Extra::where("exa_form_id", $distance->asd_form_id)->get();
    foreach($options as $option){
      $input_name = "option_" . $option->exa_id;
      $input_option = $request->$input_name;
      if(!is_null($input_option)){
         $input_name_extra = "extraoptions_" . $option->exa_id;
         $input_option_extra = $request->$input_name_extra;                      

         $registrationextra = new ExtraRegistration();
         $registrationextra->iea_registration_id = $registration->isg_id;
         $registrationextra->iea_extra_id = $input_option;
         $registrationextra->iea_extraoption_id = $input_option_extra;
         $registrationextra->iea_price = $option->exa_price;
         $registrationextra->save();

         }               

       }

$registration->isg_options = $input_option;
$registration->isg_option_extra_id = $input_option_extra;
```

**Edit:**
I want a check before it makes a new ExtraRegistration. that if the price that is in the registration already exists in that registration_id(in ExtraRegistration) it doesnt make another record in the ExtraRegistration.
I want to use an if to fix the problem, but not sure where to begin..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are creating new object of `ExtraRegistration()` so its inserting/creating new record every time.

Just changes this line

```
     $registrationextra = ExtraRegistration::find($id);//any id to fetch record
```

Comment: where do i put that line?

Comment: In place of this line `$registrationextra = new ExtraRegistration();`

Comment: Oh ok, but now i get an error saying: Creating default object from empty value. (in registration->isg_id)

Comment: Can you show your updated code and check what are you getting in `$registrationextra`?

Comment: i did dump and die after the find id, and it said null

Comment: That`s why you are getting this error, basically you have to find record from `ExtraRegistration` model, `find($id)` is just example I gave. `ExtraRegistration` model`s table must have some column from which you can fetch single record and then update it.

Answer (score 0):

It will probably be easier for you if you just use `firstOrCreate` method that Laravel provides out of the box.

*You can check it here:*
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#other-creation-methods

That way, you will be able to retrieve the record that you are looking for, if there is any and then perform all the changes on it. If that record doesn't exist, Laravel will create the new record for you which you'll be able to update.

I hope this helps!